# .Net 6 Blazor Server-Side Azure ADB2C Sign Out Issue

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, blazor-server-side, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, .net-6.0

I was starting a brand new project using .Net 5 and Azure ADB2C, but then .Net 6 came out so we decided to go ahead and re-create the small amount of code we had in .Net 6. One thing that was working but now it isn't anymore is the Sign Out functionality. I made no changes on the Azure AD B2C side of things.. On the .Net 5 project all I have to do is send the user to "MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignOut" to sign them out and that was working as long as I had the following code to send the user back to the home page (sign in page) automatically:

```
 services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
 {
      // Configures the Sign Out action to redirect back to the home page, which will navigate to the login page
      options.Events.OnSignedOutCallbackRedirect = async context =>
      {
           context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(context.Options.SignedOutRedirectUri);
           context.HandleResponse();
       };
}
```

On the .Net 6 version I kept all my code very similarly (even the packages are the same) so I'm not sure why that URL stopped working. After doing some research I found this MS documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/openid-connect#send-a-sign-out-request to create a special URL with Azure ADB2C for "end_session_endpoint" but when I navigate to it, it doesn't do anything besides redirecting me back to the application still signed in.

Here are the Packages I'm using:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph" Version="4.10.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web" Version="1.20.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI" Version="1.20.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="6.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
```

And here's a sample of what I have on my Program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Set static properties to hold Configuration and Environment
ConfigurationHelper.Configuration = builder.Configuration;
ConfigurationHelper.Environment = builder.Environment;

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAdB2C"));

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy
     options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor().AddMicrosoftIdentityConsentHandler();
var app = builder.Build();
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fixing other unrelated issues, sending the user to the URL "MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignOut" is working. As I understand the Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI is running the sign out code for me, and the code I have on startup can hookup the sign out callback event to redirect the user. I still think it's weird that the Azure AD B2C "end_session_endpoint" wasn't working for me but maybe it's something related to how Microsoft.Identity.Web manages the session.

Comment: Leonardo.... what was the other, unrelated issue that helped solving the problem above? I have exactly same logout redirect problem and been stuck for a couple of days now...

Comment: I don't remember exactly, I think I had something missing on my Startup.cs that had nothing to do with the authentication/logout problem.

Comment: Yea... I have found the problem, and it was indeed in the Program.cs. 
// The exact order of the below settings is needed for the correct AzureAD authentication/log in/out functionality
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
    endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
});

app.Run();